# unsubscriptable object

Tags: python, image, image-processing, colors, python-imaging-library

I'm using PIL

```
    im = Image.open(teh_file)
    if im:
        colors = im.resize( (1,1), Image.ANTIALIAS).getpixel((0,0)) # simple way to get average color
        red = colors[0] # and so on, some operations on color data
```

The problem is, on a few (very few, particulary don't know why those exactly, simple jpegs) I get 'unsubscriptable object' on line "colors[0]". Tried:

```
if colors:
```

gets true and goes on.

```
if len(colors):
```

gives 'len() of unsized object'

1. What condition should I apply not to get this exception?
2. What's the cause of the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the PIL docs:

```
getpixel

im.getpixel(xy) => value or tuple

Returns the pixel at the given position. If the image is a multi-layer image, this method returns a tuple.
```

So it seems that some of your images are multilayer, and some are single-layer.

Answer (score 2):

As noted in another answer, `getpixel` returns either a single value, or a tuple. You could check the type and do the appropriate action in the following ways:

```
if isinstance(colors, tuple):
    color = colors[0]
else:
    color = colors
# Do other stuff
```

or:

```
try:
    color = colors[0]
except: # Whatever the exception is - IndexError or whatever
    color = colors
# Do other stuff
```

The second way is probably more Pythonic.

Answer (score 2):

Ok the case was, that when B&W images have no RGB band (L band), it returns an integer with the pixel color single value, not a list of rgb values. The solution is to check bands

```
im.getbands()
```

or the simpler for my needs was:

```
        if isinstance(colors, tuple):
            values = {'r':colors[0], 'g':colors[1], 'b':colors[2]}
        else:
            values = {'r':colors, 'g':colors, 'b':colors}
```

Comment: dict(zip('rgb', colors if isinstance(colors, tuple) else [colors]*3))